# Plotting 2 functions in a 3D chart

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am new to MATLAB. I have 2 functions,`z=sin(x)` and 
`y=cos(x)`. I want to plot them in a **3D** (x,y,z) chart (but not with subplot), `z=sin(x)` in plane X-Z and `y=cos(x)` in plane X-Y. As I have seen, standard plot or plot3d functions are not obvious to use. May be needed some axis manipulation, etc, but I don't have it.
I would like to know the solution if only I would or any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try sharing what specific difficulties you have and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a small example of what you want to do

```
clear;clc; %clear variables from workspace and clean commadn line
x=-pi:0.1:pi; %define x
cero=zeros(size(x)); %create a vector of zeros
z=sin(x);
y=cos(x);

hold on %tell matlab to plot averything together
plot3(x,cero,z,'g');
plot3(x,y,cero,'r');
grid on; %pretty self-describing
view([1,1,1]) %set viewpoint to not se just a plane
hold off %stop ploting everything together
```

Ask if you don't get some of the lines

Comment: It works fine and comments are cleare. I have learnt a lot from it. Ander, thanx.